# Using Google Colab -- GPU Device not found error

Tags: tensorflow, gpu, google-colaboratory

Not sure how to proceed - ive refreshed/restarted the runtime several times, switching hardware acceleration setting to none, then back to GPU, back to none, to TPU and so on just to refresh it. Using GPU setting currently and receiving this error: [Google-colab error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Yjb5N.png)

Comment: hey check here this is must be the case https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/issues/34385

Comment: :/ so far tried  pip install tf-nightly-gpu and %tensorflow_version 2.x as it suggests after putting it @ the top -- still not registering a GPU -- is it possible GPUs just arent available?

Comment: No that never happened to me

Comment: OMG  - i had my vpn on and thats why it wasnt coming up - google colab would allow me to have the GPU setting on but the VPN also being on meant that it wasn't actually connected

Answer (score 0):

Don't use a VPN while connecting to Google Colab or else you will think that you're connected to the GPU